# React native flexbox not using all available space

Tags: react-native, flexbox

[Here is the code, I want to make center to container but when i put {flex:1} it not worked and data inside the container will be hide.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuWi7.png)

[Here is the output screen without using {flex:1}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPo5u.png)

[Here is the output screen while using {flex:1}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BApmC.png)

I want to center the container with using {flex:1}

Comment: DO NOT use image to display your code, please

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in my [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/center-justify-) it works as expected.
I tinted the background so you can see that the complete available space is used.

```js
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function () {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>flex1</Text>
      <Text>flex2</Text>
      <Text>flex3</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

**EDIT:**

Try to add `width` and `height` 100%:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: I have tried width:"100%" and height:"100%" but still it doesn't working. The data inside the container display at the top of screen instead of center.